# How can I convert a mail address to a hash in scala

Tags: scala, hash

I want to take the hash of my mail addresses and write it to the log file.

```
logger.info(s"[RestService] Get permission request for $email")
```

this is my case but  How can I get the hash of the email.

Helper or method?

Comment: What kind of hash? Any? Because every JVM object has `hashCode()` method that _should_ match `equals` implementation (it is on implementer), and `String`s have it implemented.

Comment: The purpose here is that we need to be able to reuse e-mail addresses after they have been hashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create an object and overwrite the `hashCode` method. Then use the `scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3` to create your hash code.

```
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

object TestMurmurHash {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val email = MyObject("my_email@google.com")
    println(s"This is my email hash: $email and this is my hash: ${email.hashCode()}")

  }

  case class MyObject(val email: String) {

    override def equals(o: Any): Boolean = {
      this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()
    }

    override def hashCode(): Int = {
      MurmurHash3.stringHash(email)
    }

    def mailToHash(): Int = {
      MurmurHash3.stringHash(email)
    }
  }

}
```

output:

```
This is my email hash: MyObject(my_email@google.com) and this is my hash: -585889836
```

Comment: good but how to write own methot and I want use everywhere  . Ex: def mailToHash

Comment: What is the point of using `App` if you are going to write the `main` yourself? You are just having the worst of all words. Second, `hashCode` has to be consistent with `equals`, the best on those cases is always have  a custom method.

Comment: @KemalDurmus just create a method with this signature. I updated the answer. I case you need to have a Util class use this method inside a Util and any other object can use it.

Comment: thank you your solutions is good but I use diffrent solutions. I write hash helper and add project other package

Comment: `def hashEmail(email: String): String = {
    HASH_FUNCTION.hashString(email, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString
  }`